# How does the github website work (architecture)?

Tags: git, architecture, diff, github

Github is a truly amazing service. I'm keen to understand what their architecture is like and how they fit the different pieces together; how they store the repositories, how they access those repositories to show file contents, how they handle displaying diffs, etc. Could someone give an overview of the technologies and techniques they use, so I can study them to expand my knowledge and in turn skills?

Comment: Why don't you ask this question on the github website? It's more likely github developers will properly answer your question rather than random people here on SO...

Comment: They use `Git` which is a free and open source distributed version control system designed to handle everything from small to very large projects with speed and efficiency. see https://git-scm.com.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The core of Github is the open-source software `git`, which is a distributed version control and source code management software. Github adds many features onto `git`'s functionality, including issue tracking, wiki, access control, etc.

However, Github is proprietary software, and many of it's internals remain unknown to general public.

In order to find out how pieces are fit together, I suggest following the leads below:

- [Github's official Engineering Blog](https://github.com/blog/category/engineering), which covers a wide range of topics of the design of the platform.

  - especially [this article](https://github.com/blog/530-how-we-made-github-fast), an extensive overview written by Github CTO.
- [Projects that power Github](https://github.com/showcases/projects-that-power-github), an officially curated list of open-source projects that power Github. Here are a few highlights:

  - rails - web backend
  - jekyll - blog engine behind *Github Pages*
  - elasticsearch - search engine
  - hubot - a chat bot for task automation
  - ace - browswer based code editor
  - d3 - js lib for graphs and charts
  - resque - background works
- [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/), an open-source alternative to Github, which offers pretty much the same functionalities.

  - Read the source code of GitLab and you'll get to know how GitLab (and Github as well) works under the hood.
  - [GitLab Architecture Overview](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/development/architecture.html). This article is definitely a good entry point.

I stole a system layout diagram from *Gitlab Architecture Overview*. Bet you've already get a hang of how gitlab works from this diagram.

(There surely are lots of difference between Github and GitLab. But an open-source project is always better for someone who wants to learn, isn't it?)

[image: GitLab system layout diagram]